# game engine, how to organize animation and etc. in android?

Tags: android, animation, game-engine

I'm quite new to android and i want to make some animation (simple game later) like i did on windows (all programatically).
So I have questions what classes should be responsible for.

Activity
It's a base class for whole logic like updating variables (computing move etc.)
Should I create a new Thread on onCreate and run it onResume ? (I need continuous computing for moving objects)

View
Only for drawing animation
onDraw method for clearing Canvas (how to do this quickly? drawRect is efficent ? ) and drawing objects.
Should I invalidate that view or just call onDraw 30 times per second?

Regards
razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/index.html

Comment: thanks, I've managed to do some animation, but I see that I should try OpenGL.
Another thing, is there option to speed up emulator? it shows my animation with ~14-15fps (android 2.2, core i5-750@3.3GHz) whereas HTC Desire shows my animation with ~59-60fps.
quite big differences.

Comment: cpu usage ~7-8% :/ why emulator doesn't use full power? (at least one core to 100% percent) ?

Comment: For now, there is no hardware acceleration for graphics in the Emulator. Google engineer claimed they are doing their best to solve the problem.

Comment: great news: they just added hardware acceleration support few days ago ;) enjoy